# Different results on using function and it's content

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, knn, imputation

I was trying to understand the working of the function `fast_knn` of `impyute` library. So, I tried to execute it line by line in order to understand the working. Here it is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
def shepards(distances, power=2):
    return to_percentage(1/np.power(distances, power))

def to_percentage(vec):
    return vec/np.sum(vec)

data_temp = np.arange(25).reshape((5, 5)).astype(np.float)
data_temp[0][2] =  np.nan
k=4
eps=0
p=2
distance_upper_bound=np.inf
leafsize=10
idw_fn=shepards
init_impute_fn=mean

nan_xy = np.argwhere(np.isnan(data_temp))
data_temp_c = init_impute_fn(data_temp)
kdtree = KDTree(data_temp_c, leafsize=leafsize)
for x_i, y_i in nan_xy:
    distances, indices = kdtree.query(data_temp_c[x_i], k=k+1, eps=eps,
                                      p=p, distance_upper_bound=distance_upper_bound)
    # Will always return itself in the first index. Delete it.
    distances, indices = distances[1:], indices[1:]
    # Add small constant to distances to avoid division by 0
    distances += 1e-3
    weights = idw_fn(distances)
    # Assign missing value the weighted average of `k` nearest neighbours
    data_temp[x_i][y_i] = np.dot(weights, [data_temp_c[ind][y_i] for ind in indices])
data_temp
```

This outputs:

```
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        , 10.06569379,  3.        ,  4.        ],
       [ 5.        ,  6.        ,  7.        ,  8.        ,  9.        ],
       [10.        , 11.        , 12.        , 13.        , 14.        ],
       [15.        , 16.        , 17.        , 18.        , 19.        ],
       [20.        , 21.        , 22.        , 23.        , 24.        ]])
```

whereas the function has a different output. The code :

```
from impyute import fast_knn
import numpy as np
data_temp = np.arange(25).reshape((5, 5)).astype(np.float)
data_temp[0][2] =  np.nan
fast_knn(data_temp, k=4)
```

and the output

```
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        , 16.78451885,  3.        ,  4.        ],
       [ 5.        ,  6.        ,  7.        ,  8.        ,  9.        ],
       [10.        , 11.        , 12.        , 13.        , 14.        ],
       [15.        , 16.        , 17.        , 18.        , 19.        ],
       [20.        , 21.        , 22.        , 23.        , 24.        ]])
``
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be discrepancies with the  [GitHub repository](https://github.com/eltonlaw/impyute/blob/master/impyute/imputation/cs/fast_knn.py) code and library source code ( the repository has not been updated). The following is the library source code :

```
def fast_knn(data, k=3, eps=0, p=2, distance_upper_bound=np.inf, leafsize=10, **kwargs):    
    null_xy = find_null(data)
    data_c = mean(data)
    kdtree = KDTree(data_c, leafsize=leafsize)

    for x_i, y_i in null_xy:
        distances, indices = kdtree.query(data_c[x_i], k=k+1, eps=eps,
                                          p=p, distance_upper_bound=distance_upper_bound)
        # Will always return itself in the first index. Delete it.
        distances, indices = distances[1:], indices[1:]
        weights = distances/np.sum(distances)
        # Assign missing value the weighted average of `k` nearest neighbours
        data[x_i][y_i] = np.dot(weights, [data_c[ind][y_i] for ind in indices])
    return data
```

The weights are computed in a different manner (not using the `shepards` function). Hence, the difference in outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you used [the code on the current `master` branch](https://github.com/eltonlaw/impyute/blob/e76179bcba5296714f0b35f00c7618d001d3ff35/impyute/imputation/cs/fast_knn.py) of [impyute](https://github.com/eltonlaw/impyute). But the impyute package version you used maybe v0.0.8 — the current recent version — [whose code is at the `release/0.0.8` branch](https://github.com/eltonlaw/impyute/blob/release/0.0.8/impyute/imputation/cs/fast_knn.py).

The difference in the definition of `fast_knn` is below.

On the current `master` branch:

```py
# Will always return itself in the first index. Delete it.
distances, indices = distances[1:], indices[1:]
# Add small constant to distances to avoid division by 0
distances += 1e-3
weights = idw_fn(distances)
```

On `release/0.0.8` branch:

```py
# Will always return itself in the first index. Delete it.
distances, indices = distances[1:], indices[1:]
weights = distances/np.sum(distances)
```

If you use the code in the `release/0.0.8` branch, you will get the same result as you use the impyute package.